# find control inside datalist in button event

Tags: asp.net, datalist

I had data list as label for Question and textarea for Answer ,as
datalist render Question on label and the user will add the Answer in
text area as the answers inserted in database. I did my code , but
when I add my code to find the controls (label,textarea) they returned
with null value although I add answers for the Questions .

```
protected void BT_submit_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{

    Label QID = (Label)Dl_Question.FindControl("lbl_QID");
    HtmlTextArea QAnswer = (HtmlTextArea)Dl_Question.FindControl("Txt_Answer");
}
```

DataList code:

```
<asp:DataList ID="Dl_Question" runat="server" onitemdatabound="Dl_Question_ItemDataBound"                                                                          onitemcommand="Dl_Question_ItemCommand">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="lbl_QID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' Visible="false">
      </asp:Label><br />
      <asp:Label ID="Lbl_Question" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Question") %>'></asp:Label>  <br />
      <textarea id="Txt_Answer" cols="80" rows="5" runat="server"></textarea>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Comment: can you post the DataList binding code?

Comment: You want to retrieve the answer for each question. Correct?

Comment: My apologies that I am having a hard time understanding, is that a yes? You want to retrieve the answer for each question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume you are looking at higher level than you think. You might need something like this:

```
Label QID = Dl_Question.**Items[n]**.FindControl("lbl_QID") as Label;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to bother specifying the control heir achy use a [recursive algorithm](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/06/recursive-pagefindcontrol.html).